# When building a form, where is the best place to set label values?

Tags: symfony, twig

My project is meant to be multilingual, I'm far from finished but so far all my twig templates use the **trans** filter.

Now when building forms I want my labels to be translated as well, so far here is one of several formbuilder classes, the question is: Should I set values for the labels here or inside the twig templates so I can use again the twig 'trans' filter?

```
<?php

namespace MG\AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CustomersHomesType extends AbstractType
{

    private $customersId = null;

    public function __construct($customersId){
        $this->customersId = $customersId;
;
    }
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customers_id', 'hidden', array('data'=>$this->customersId,'required'=>true))
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label'=>'Name:','required'=>true))
            ->add('streetAddress1', 'text', array('label'=>'Street Address:','required'=>true))
            ->add('streetAddress2', 'text', array('label'=>'Street Address:','required'=>false))
            ->add('city', 'text', array('label'=>'City:','required'=>true))
            ->add('state', 'text', array('label'=>'State:','required'=>true))
            ->add('zipcode', 'text', array('label'=>'Zip Code:','required'=>true))
            ->add('type', 'choice', array(
                    'expanded'=>false,
                    'label'=>'Address Type:',
                    'choices'   => array('billing' => 'Billing Address ', 'work' => 'Work Address ', 'shipping'=>'Shipping Address '),
                    'required'  => true,
            ))
            ->add('subdivision', 'text', array('label'=>'Subdivision:','required'=>false))
            ->add('directions', 'textarea', array('label'=>'Directions Or Comments:','required'=>false))

            ->add('phone', 'text', array('label'=>'Phone #1:','required'=>false))
            ->add('phone2', 'text', array('label'=>'Phone #2:','required'=>false))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label'=>'Save'))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MG\AdminBundle\Entity\CustomersHomes'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mg_adminbundle_customershomes';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long day answering your questions....

Best place to add labels in in the form but using the translations.

In your form..

```
->add('blah', 'text', array(
    ... etc ...
    'label' => 'vendor.bundle.field.label',
    // For bundle named Vendor\Bundle
)
```

Then in your translations files (located in `Resources/translations/messages.[locale].[filetype] (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) (this is in YAML format)

```
vendor:
    bundle:
        field:
            label: the label that you wanted to show
        field2:
            biscuits: you can call it what ever you want
```

This way you can make a bunch of translations files and then make your site multi-lingual (providing the files are there, it falls back to your set locale or fallback otherwise) rather than having to dig in later in the date to edit actual text. Also there is only one folder (or group of folder `Resources/translations` that you need to update later on rather than editing actual class data.

This same system also works for any kind of validations but those translations need to be places in the `Resources/translations/validators.[locale].[filetype]`. Still very handy.

If they don't show up immediately then try clearing your cache.

Comment: I'm very appreciative of your time, I find that by asking questions I learn quicker, also I keep a good reference to come back to here on stackoverflow. Again thank you so much.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help. As I mentioned in the other answer.. a good place to look for good use of what Symfony has to offer is the Sylius Bundle (https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius) as well as the FOSUserBundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle). The Symfony CMF bundle may also a great source but as far as I know it makes use of PHPCR which I haven't invested any time in so I've pretty much steered away from it meaning I can't attest to it's learning virtues.